# Detect text in hindi using mlKit

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I am creating an app which takes the picture and recognize the text from it and provides it as the output. I am using mlkit from the firebase for this purpose. So far I am able to detect the text in English. Now I want it to detect the text in Hindi. Also, I am using on-device detection for detecting the text.

Can anyone guide me with this hurdle?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase [overview of the text recognition API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/recognize-text) starts with this:

> With ML Kit's text recognition APIs, you can recognize text **in any Latin-based language** (and more, with [Cloud-based text recognition](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages)).

Since Hindi uses non Latin-based characters, it can't be recognized by ML Kit's on-device API. The Cloud-based API that is linked **does** support many more character sets, including Hindi.

So you'll either have to use the Cloud-based API, or train your own model to recognize Hindi text.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I came across the same thing but i was wondering if it can be done ondevice.

Comment: It *can* probably be done on the device, but you'd have to find or train another model for that. The model built into ML Kit only handles Latin-based languages.